# UE5 - Full-screen borderless window (no title bar) in macOS?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

Trying to build a MacOS app that will share the screen with another app, but while I can get the app to open in Windowed mode rather than the default Fullscreen, and I can set the size in Blueprints, the window always has the default Mac title bar.

- I have set the “Borderless” window option in game settings.
- In Blueprints I've used the "r.setRes XXXX x XXXXw" console command.
- In Windows I can make the Windowed Fullscreen option work, but on a Mac it seems the title bar is always there.

Does anyone know of an approach that would give me a true borderless, chromeless window in macOS?
(also posted on Unreal Forum)

Comment: Please let us know if you find an answer 